Not able to authenticate into Nexus docker repository
I deployed Nexus using a docker compose file, and created a docker hosted repository. While trying to authenticate into the repository using docker login ip:port, I got the eror message below. My reposotry configuration is as seen on the image.

Username: admin
Password:
INFO[0023] Error logging in to endpoint, trying next endpoint  error="Get \"https://ip:5000/v2/\": dial tcp ip:5000: connect: connection refused"
Get "https://ip:5000/v2/": dial tcp ip:5000: connect: connection refused



I used the admin username and password of my nexus server while trying to authenticate into docker repository. My thinking is that the issue might be with the password i am using to authenticate into the docker repository. Is this issue associated with the password? if yes, which password can I use as I am unable to set a password while creating the repository on nexus?
also, I added my host in the /etc/docker/daemon.json to by pass the issue but it still throws the same error.

{
          "insecure-registries" : ["nexus-ip:5000"]
}



Docker won’t allow credentials to pass over http (even with insecure registry enabled).  You’ll need to configure Nexus Repo to server content over HTTPS, and then use an HTTPS port.

Thanks, @rseddon, this helps. I created an nginx proxy manager to server https requests and it solved the issues
